# Tunneling from one unix server to other unix server using ssh

Tags: networking, ssh, unix, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to connect one Unix server to another. Direct login is possible, but logging in through a tunnel is failing. I'm creating the tunnel connection using:

```
ssh -N -f -L 6002:bsc2:22 lsm@107.108.204.177
```

Comment: Error log maybe?

Answer (score 0):

`-f` puts the process in the background so you are unable to enter your password, set up key based authentication.

I personally wouldn't be putting up IP address to gateway machines with my username on the internet either, this is a massive security flaw!